# Does not return java function annotation

Tags: java, throw

Is there any way to force the compiler (annotation or othewise) to realize a java function is never returning (i.e. always throwing), so that subsequently it will not error out its usages as the last statement in other functions returning non void?

Here's a simplified/made-up example:

```
int add( int x, int y ) {
    throwNotImplemented();  // compiler error here: no return value.
}

// How can I annotate (or change) this function, so compiling add will not yield
// an error since this function always throws?
void throwNotImplemented() {
    ... some stuff here (generally logging, sometimes recovery, etc)
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear. What are you trying _exactly_?

Comment: I can't understand what is the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what changes need to be made to throwNotImplemented (while keeping it's funtionality intact), so that add function can compile as-is, but without an error.

Comment: I don't understand why you want this. If you will force the compiler to break if a method is not implemented and should be overridden, you should use 'abstract`: `abstract int add(int x, int y);`. Then you have to implement it in a subclass. If you're not "able" to implement `add` at the moment but "reserve" the method signaturem throwing `NotImplementedException` is just fine. Documenting the method's state using JavaDoc does the rest. It depends on your intention.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not possible.

Note, however, that you can easily work it around as follows:

```
int add( int x, int y ) {
    throw notImplemented();
}

Exception notImplemented() {
    ... some stuff here (generally logging, sometimes recovery, etc)
    return new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not throw directly from the not implemented method?

```
int add( int x, int y ) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}
```

This will compile fine even if the method does not return an int. And it uses a [standard JDK exception](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsupportedOperationException.html), which is meant to be used in such situations.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @assylias.

The throwNotImplemented method needs to do extra actions (logging, recovery, etc), which means just throwing in `add` won't be enough.
And adding those actions to `add` method leads to duplication (i.e., a `multiply` method will need to have them as well).